# When a game goes into background on iOS, what should I do to avoid getting stuck?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, air, starling-framework

I am doing a game on iOS using starling AIR. It can running on iPhone and iPad. It contains a lot of animation and needs to connect to the server when playing.

The problem is, when the game enter background or the screen locked for a while, sometimes the game will stuck, sometimes it will restart, sometimes it will running normally.

I have read the *AIR iOS – Background Behavior*. 
I know that when the application is suspended, os will handle memory optimization, it depends on the apps running foreground.

But what should I do when the game enter background ?
Let the game restart or run normally is fine, but avoiding stuck.

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is save your application state when your app is suspended, and restore it when its restored. There's a failry lengthy tutorial on Adobe Devnet showing how they recommend doing that.

[Saving State in AIR Applications(Link)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/saving_state_air_apps.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just read the article. But my game is always connecting to the server, whenever it exits(or crashes), it will restart from where it exited. I think it is not necessary to save state locally.

Comment: When the game goes to background, would it be throttled down to 4 fps in the background automatically? What should I do to avoid getting stuck when it restart? When the game needs restart, I want it restart Immediately rather than stuck for a while before restart.

Comment: You can't assume it will restart instantly. The application context may be destroyed if that memory is needed by something else. If that has happened, Starling will have to load your textures into memory again. This is slow enough process for users to notice. Since you cannot prevent this happening, you will need to give the user feedback when re-starting that the game is reinitializing.

Comment: So you mean that I don't need to do anything? oh, it's not a good user experience. Last weekend, I found another game also using starling AIR. It didn't show what I mentioned above. But I don't know how does it handled this ? Thus, I think that there is something need to do.

Comment: If you want to know, the game is MIAMI HOT WAVES developed by UBI.

Answer (score -1):

"What to Do When Moving to the Background" and "Memory Usage for Background Apps" section of the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) clearly explains this.

Comment: your answer, while true, does not address who to implement this using Adobe AIR. AIR is middleware, not Objective C, so its not as simple as following the apple developer docs.